# Tortoise SVN File Version Property for Inno Setup

Tags: tortoisesvn, versioning, inno-setup

I am struggling to find an answer to this online.

I am using Inno Setup to create an installer for several files. I know InnoSetup can check file versions and wont overwrite with old versions which is brilliant.

However, I cant figure out how to make tortoise SVN add the "Version" property to its files.

I would rather not use the "touch" flag in Inno Setup for all the files.

I am fairly new to versioning (the creation of version ID's), and any 'usefull links' would be greatly appreciated on this one

Comment: If you have files in a working copy, you should not try to "install" that working copy elsewhere.  Only use TSVN itself (or another SVN client) to manage a TSVN working copy.  If you're trying to do something else, perhaps you need to explain your situation better.  Normally the roles of these two applications do not overlap.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the kind of "version" Inno Setup checks.

Inno Setup checks the executable (`.DLL`/`.EXE`) version info (it's a Windows resource embedded in the file - see [`Version Info Resource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN for details), like you see if you right-click an application in Windows Explorer, look at `Properties->Details`, and see things like:

```
File Description     Some Application Description
Type                 Application
File Version         2.5.1.247
Product Name         Some Product Name
Product Version      2.0.0.0
Copyright            © 2013, Some Company Name
```